# Как отключить эффект анимации

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно отключить эффект анимации появления формы? Чтобы она не выскакивала снизу при загрузке. http://codepen.io/neel2292/pen/jbjMLe`введите сюда код`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все просто. Удалите классы "animated slideInUp" в теге div, который идет сразу после body. также думаю стоит удалить "animated slideInDown" немного ниже в теге P с классом "installment-label"

Comment: Спасибо! Все получилось :)